# Converting character to class date

Tags: sql, r

I have this query

```
sql <- "select 
    observationid::text,id,date, ST_X(location::geometry) as lon, ST_Y(location::geometry) as lat
    from test
    where date>=  '1850-01-01' and date  <'1851-01-01'"
datain<-dbGetQuery(dbh,sql)
```

that I am running from R. What I would like to do is to set date range outside the query with something like

```
datamin <- '1850-01-01'
datamax <- '1851-01-01'
sql <- "select 
    observationid::text,id,date, ST_X(location::geometry) as lon, ST_Y(location::geometry) as lat
    from test
    where date>=  datamin and date  <datamax"
datain<-dbGetQuery(dbh,sql)
```

but I get this error

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  column "datamin" does not exist
```

Many thanks

Comment: R does not interpret variables inside strings like some other programming languages.  You need to use `paste` to construct your query string: `sql <- paste("select blah blah where date >= ", datamin, " and ...")`. You should read some [introductory R manuals](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf)

Comment: Sorry but I it is not working (because of the select?)

Comment: print the `sql` var and see whether it contains what you think it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
datamin <- '1850-01-01'
datamax <- '1851-01-01'

sql <- sprintf("select 
        observationid::text,id,date, ST_X(location::geometry) as lon, ST_Y(location::geometry) as lat
        from test
        where date>= '%s' and date < '%s';",datamin,datamax)
datain<-dbGetQuery(dbh,sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to code datamin and datamax as dates:

```
datamin <- as.Date('1850-01-01')
datamax <- as.Date('1851-01-01')
```